# how to find a local resource from dependent jar?

Tags: java, file, jar, classloader

I have written a code that is packed to `1.jar`

with this code:

```
    return isProd? "/etc/waze/automation/devices.json":
            DeviceRepositoryFromJsonFile.class.getClassLoader().getResource("devices.json").getPath().toString();
```

devices.json is here:

[image]

I have another project that depends on `1.jar`

however the `classLoader` doesn't find the local `devices.json` file but rather one packed in the jar

anyhow it shows the file doesn't exist.

[image]

How can I fix this? just use a absolute path anyhow?

Comment: Where's the local devices.json locate? I would rather recommend you to place it in location relative to classpath so that it can be found somewhere from classloader.

Comment: I have added to my location. Can you please give an example of what you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If as in your screenshot the devices.json locate in the src/main/resources and the package have successfully treat that as the package path and put in the jar file root directory, then you can just find the file via:

```
DeviceRepositoryFromJsonFile.class.getResource("/devices.json");
```

Note the "/" slash is important to indicate that to search from the root of the classpath.

Answer (score 1):

It does not answer your question directly, but it may solve your problems faster.

As far as I can see you try to detect the absolute path to json file and pass it to another method so this file could be processed. Instead, it could be done simpler:

```
public byte[] getDevicesJsonBytes() {
    return isProd
        ? IOUtils.toByteArray(ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO_PROD_FILE)
        : IOUtils.toByteArray(DeviceRepositoryFromJsonFile.class.getResourceAsStream(RESOURCE_CLASSPATH);
}
```

The common way to read classpath resources it to use `getResourceAsStream` on `class` or `classLoader` instance. Also, many frameworks have their own resources abstractions, but I guess you don't need them now.